# Am I correctly interpreting hypergeometric probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

Consider the following problem:

> There are 10 batteries in a drawer, 4 of which are dead. If we randomly select 3 batteries, what is the probability that at most one is dead?

The meaning of ***at most*** is confusing me, as it would appear it is different than saying ***exactly***.

I used the following to get an answer of $0.50$:

$\frac{{4\choose1}{10-4\choose3-1}}{10\choose3}$

[StatTrek](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/hypergeometric.aspx#cumprob), however, indicates that this is the correct answer when looking for *exactly* one that is dead and the cumulative probability of $0.67$ should be used for *at most*.

Which is the correct answer in the context of this problem? Why would it make a difference if *exactly* and *at most* mean the exact same thing considering we're looking for only one item anyway?

Comment: You have to also consider the probability that none of them are dead.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "at most $1$ battery is dead" means that we can have either **exactly** $0$ dead batteries or **exactly** $1$ dead battery. It seems you have calculated the probability that we have **exactly** $1$ dead battery, i.e. $P(X=1)$. Thus, we need to calculate the probability we have **exactly** $0$ dead batteries, i.e. $P(X=0)$. Due to the fact that the $2$ events are disjoint, we simply add the $2$ probabilities.

Comment: Oops; overlooked the possibility of zero. Is there a change I could make to the formula instead of calculating the probabilities separately and then adding them? If the problem was asking about choosing 50 out of 1000, I can't imagine we would calculate the probability for each of 0 through 50 and add them all together.

Comment: @HEATH3N In this specific example, we could just write in a more compact form:$$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^1 \dfrac{\dbinom{4}{k}\cdot \dbinom{6}{3-k}}   {\dbinom{10}{3}}.$$ (I guess now you can generalize it in the case you describe.) I am not sure how we can handle this sum, if not term by term. However, I have the feeling that the purpose of this exercise does not lie in evaluating the exact number, but setting the formula correctly.

Comment: If there is a need to evaluate the number (as in our case), then I have the feeling that the operations won't be that hard and not that many.